# Best place placement to a 'Proceed Button' - along with huge graphics

Tags: gui-design, ux-field

Based on the mock-up attached, which do you think will be the best placement for the button?[image]

Comment: Based on the fact that pagination is usually located at the bottom of the page I'd say that the proceed button should also be located at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The button should be on the bottom. If the issue is the graphic is so big and you think the user won't scroll, then you should ask yourself if that graphic is essential to be seen. In that case, you can make the steppers clickable (breadcrumbs in the right don't seem logical) - https://m1.material.io/components/steppers.html#steppers-usage

Answer (score 1):

There is really not enough information provided to choose properly. UX isn't just about mockups - it's about understanding user needs and providing them the best solution and you gave no information about the user or their needs.

But here's a quick starter overview of pros and cons for every layout:

---

### Layout A

#### Pros:

- **Central Focus**: The button is near the center at the bottom, which could be directly in the user's [view after reading the content](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/) (as lstclair suggested).
- **Balance**: The placement of the button may give a balanced appearance to the page, especially if the main content area is centered.

#### Cons:

- **Unconventional Placement**: Users may not expect a navigation button to be centered at the bottom, which could lead to confusion or a longer time to locate the button.
- **Scrolling**: On longer pages, users might have to scroll down to access the button, which could add an unnecessary step to the navigation process.

---

### Layout B

#### Pros:

- **Conventional and Predictable**: The button is in a common location for progression controls, aligning with user expectations.
- **Ease of Access**: For right-handed users, the bottom right position is easy to reach, especially on mobile devices.
- **Visual Hierarchy**: Separated from the main content, the button stands out more and is recognized as a separate action area.

#### Cons:

- **Left-handed Accessibility**: Left-handed users might find it slightly less comfortable to reach the button if they're using a mobile device.
- **Page Balance**: If the rest of the content is not aligned to complement this placement, it may throw off the visual balance slightly.

Answer (score 0):

imo this depends on the importance of the graphic - If you want a user to scan through it first before continuing maybe A is the right call

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).